# Bigger Image on Mouse Over Magento

Tags: magento

Here`s my issue:
I am putting this store together with magento for selling images
http://shop.lopezi.com/

I want that on mouse over the thumbnail a new bigger image pop´s up, like for instance on shutterstock  (ex. http://shutr.bz/19lZ3cL)

Any help and tips appreciated.

Thank your very much
Nuno Lopes

Comment: CloudZoom -> http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/magento

Answer (score 1):

I think there is many free extension as well as paid extension are present for productImage zooming 
Here, I am listing free extension for product image zoom

[VS Product Image Zoom](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vs-featurezoom.html) support upto magento 1.7.1

[CueBlocks Zoom](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cueblocks-zoom.html) support upto magneto 1.6

[Magento Product zoom extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-prozoom.html) support upto magento 1.7

and Paid plugin for zoom

[Magic Zoom Plus](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magic-zoom-plus.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Product Image Zoom: Magento Extension, Magento Plug-in](http://www.temgra.com/index.php/latest-magento-extensions/product-image-zoom-magento-extension.html). check live demo from [here](http://demo.temgra.com/index.php/?___store=product_image_zoom)